# How to put placeholder in macros in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

If I launch the macro for the vector math accent, for example, then `\vec{·}` will be inserted and the cursor will automatically jump to `·` so that I can type in. It is just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for `\frac{·}{·}`. In TexMaker the placeholder seems to be `#INS#`, but it doesn't work in TexStudio.

Comment: Oh ,I got it myself. It is %|.

Comment: maybe you can add this ans answer and accept it so this question will no longer be "open" ;-)

Comment: and first of all: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234". :-)

Answer (score 12):

Use `%|` to place the cursor or `%<myname%>` to set a placeholder with text. See also the [cwl description in the manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).

Comment: Why do you link to the documentation for cwl and not to the documentation for the [macro syntax](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33)?

Comment: No special reason. I'm not sure the documentation of the macro syntax existed back then. It's the better link nowadays.

Comment: [New working link](https://texstudio-org.github.io/advanced.html#text-macros)