# Automatically suggest arguments for user defined commands

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, texstudio

When using the command `\ref{` it automatically suggests several arguments, such as `eqn:equation1`, `fig:figure1`, and so on.

I have defined the command `\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Fig. \ref{#1}}`, which rather simply puts `Fig.` in front of the reference number.

Is there any way to make `\fref{` automatically suggest arguments, as `\ref{` does? Ideally, it would only suggest arguments that begin with `fig:`.

This is for TexStudio, which controls this (as far as I know).

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a function of your editor and not of LaTeX.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yeah, now what you mention it. Edited the question.

Comment: Unrelated: the definition should be `\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}}` in order to avoid page breaks between `Fig.` and the corresponding number. BTW: there's also packages like `cleveref` which you might want to consider http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want `\fref` to behave like a regular `\ref` command. TXS infers the semantics of a command from .cwl files. See the [FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands) and [the manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).

- create a file `user.cwl` in your [settings directory](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored) with the content `\fref{label}#r`
- open TeXstudio and check `user.cwl` at Options -> Completion.

Comment: Yes! that does exactly what I want, thank you!
From reading the manual there doesn't seem to any way to limit the possible labels that come up, such as only the ones beginning with `eqn:`. Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct. Labels cannot be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

In TexStudio you can define a macro which suits your interests: [Defining New ShortCuts in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129271/defining-new-shortcuts-in-texstudio)

and you can put a placeholder in it: [How to put placeholder in macros in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150977/how-to-put-placeholder-in-macros-in-texstudio)

Comment: This doesn't do what I want :-/

Comment: Sorry, so I must have misinterpreted your question.