# Cursor in TexStudio Macro

Tags: texstudio, scripts

I have a Macro in TexStudio that does the following:

```
%SCRIPT
txt = cursor.selectedText()

editor.write("\\underbrace{"+txt+"}_{}")

cursor.clearSelection()
```

That is I select a text, it will be filled in between the first two brackets of underbrace. I would like to add that my cursor should be in the between the second pair of brackets, however the solutions I found so far in the internet have not helped. Does anybody have an idea?

Great thanks!

Comment: Hi, [this similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150977/how-to-put-placeholder-in-macros-in-texstudio) might also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
%SCRIPT
txt = cursor.selectedText()
editor.write("\\underbrace{"+txt+"}_{}")
cursor.movePosition(1,cursorEnums.Left)
```

How it works is the following: I save what I selected with my cursor in txt. Then I go ahead and write "\underbrace{txt}_{}", where txt will be substituted with what I selected before. The cursor will be afterwards at the end, therefore going one step to the left will land my cursor inside the two curly brackets.

Comment: Please explain your answer.